What is android.app.ActivityThread.IDS.xml in shared_prefs?
In the shared_prefs folder in my apps private data on Android there is a file called android.app.ActivityThread.IDS.xml and it contains this
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="IDSCount" value="10" />
</map>

I tried searching the entire android source code through https://cs.android.com/
without any mention of IDSCount
Edit1: it seems IDS is something from Samsung, it assigns a value to an app when running. I found logcat logs on Google with "IDS_TAG" and messages related to shared preferences.
IDSCount value can be 1, 2, 5, 10 or -1 or even non-existent if the app is in "NO_IDS" list.
It looks something related to power saving. But without knowing what 'IDS' stands for, I don't know if a value of 10 is better or worse than 5.
Edit2: I found references of IDSCount in my Samsung ROM : IdsController IdsController again
I still have no clue what IDS stands for.

android.app.ActivityThread.IDS.xml file stores associations between system resource identifiers and various system resources like: activities, services, layouts, etc. These associations are established during the build process and help program find the right stuff it needs when running.
